# Float right inside table not working

Tags: html, css, positioning

I wish to make the blue circles float left for odd numbers and right for even numbers. I've tried floating the elements but it doesn't seem to work.

I've used table and table-cells to achieve the centered text and logos but cannot seem to get them to inverse unless i switched the positioning of the elements

```
enter code here
```

Here is a current demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/7g7medn1/

Result Demo (re positioned dom elements to achieve result, need to do it without re positioning them):
https://jsfiddle.net/wcttx9vm/

Comment: You cant do it with floats with out re arrangement. only thing I can think of is a jquery solution or absolute positioning.

Comment: I don't see any table used in your page. Using tables/div to align the content is much easier. Do you want to use table or want to keep the div and just need content placement adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I don't understand: When you want a table, why you don't use ? A table can be used to display table-content, but not for pure layouting.

In your case I would do it like this: Take a php-file and do the "layouting" there. That means that you will do the even-odd-placement in a for-loop and switch the odd layout there. I guess it would be the easiest way.

And your current demo code can't work, since your bubble is always first in code. That is ok for the left positioning, but for right positioning it needs to be after the text. Otherwise you will screw it up.

Comment: The only issue was with the positioning from a responsive perspective, What if I re-created 2 bubbles and placed them after the content and used display: none when appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

you might need to a add class for the even columns and change floating and display properties as follows:

```
.even .content {
    display: block; 
}

.even .circle {
    float: right;
}

.even .content {
    display: inline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zxhbbwdm/4/

Comment: Hi there thanks for your solution the only issue is the text is not vertically centered for the evens I do not want to add a margin/padding because they may change/vary,.